# Configuring OleDB Query in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

We have a bunch of Excel linked files which have an embedded user name and password in them. Each of the files connect to a SQL Server instance and retrieves data via Table function or view. 
The data properties say: OLE DB Query.

I am able to create new ones by updating the existing files i.e create a copy of the file and then replacing the function/view with a new one.

However, I would like to create a brand new one from scratch. 
I looked at:

Data -> Get External Data.

Get External data -> Get Data from OLEDB Query is not an option.

Any other option is requiring me to create a connection file which I cannot do since our users need to access this linked file via network share.

How do I create a linked file with OLE DB Query?

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and create the connection file, this is standard operating procedure for Excel.  We can uncouple it and just use the connection in the worksheet.

To remove the file, go to your data tab and click the [connections] button in the [Connections] group.  Select the connection your created and click [Properties].

When the Connection Properties dialog opens, click on the [Definitions] tab.  You'll see a connection type, a connection file, and then a check box labeled 'Always use connection file' -- if this isn't unchecked, go ahead and do it now.

Note the location of the connection file, go to that location, and delete the file.

And that should take care of it for you.  Save your file and send the worksheet over to another user for testing.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This helped.